# NSData gives me an error in version 9.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2, apple-developer

Given below is my function written in swift this code works fine in 10.0 version of iPhone but gives an error in 9.0  **saying**

> CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL
>   which has no scheme Failed to load: The file
>   “Recording2017-03-06_11.08.53000.mp3” couldn’t be opened.

**partFileURL will be having**

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8F9055D-D816-4E27-BA2A-B13F0EE97709/tmp/Recording2017-03-06_11.08.53000.mp3

**This is my below function-:**

```
//function
func putPartUplaod(partFileURL:URL , partFileNumber:Int)
{
        var partfileData:Data?
        var md5hash:Any?
        var sha256hash:Any?
        //  var error: NSError?   
        let uri:URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: partFileURL.absoluteString) as URL

        //Get MD5 Digest
        do{
            print(partFileURL)
            partfileData = try NSData(contentsOf: uri, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.dataReadingMapped) as Data    
            print("hello" , partfileData);
            md5hash = partfileData?.md5().base64EncodedString()  
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}
```

Comment: What's partFileURL value that you're passing?

Comment: Im passing this : 

**/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8F9055D-D816-4E27-BA2A-B13F0EE97709/tmp/Recording2017-03-06_11.08.53000.mp3**

Comment: What is the purpose to create an URL (`uri`) from an URL (`partFileURL`)? Btw: Don't use `NSData`, `NSURL` in Swift 3

Comment: @vadian **URL (uri) from an URL (partFileURL)**  is not required sorry about it i was just trying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like `NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];` The string that you're passing in is not a valid URL, it's just a file path. For making it URL, you would need to add the scheme which would be `file://`.

Comment: -Tried works in
IPhone 7 (OS 10.2.1 ) ,
IPhone 6s (OS 10.2.1 ) ,
Iphone 6 (OS 10.2.1 ) ,
Iphone 5s (OS 10.2.1 )  but in
IPhone 5 (OS 9.3.5 )- doesnt work

Comment: @nikhil What's the error on `9.3.5`? And are you sure that the file path exists?

Comment: thank  you , i was getting error because of  "file://"

Comment: Now I got One more issue when i tried to append "file://" to that path and tried to print the path im getting this ->

**file/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B78F6B3C-9415-4F2C-B43A-7D371577B9C1/tmp/Recording2017-03-06_11.08.53000.mp3 -- file:///**

Answer (score 2):

`/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8F9055D-D816-4E27-BA2A-B13F0EE97709/tmp/Recording2017-03-06_11.08.53000.mp3`is a file path and not a url. A url has a scheme (or protocol). See your error message. Create your url with

```
URL(fileURLWithPath:"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8F9055D-D816-4E27-BA2A-B13F0EE97709/tmp/Recording2017-03-06_11.08.53000.mp3")
```

Comment: -Tried works in
IPhone 7 (OS 10.2.1 ) ,
IPhone 6s (OS 10.2.1 ) ,
Iphone 6 (OS 10.2.1 ) ,
Iphone 5s (OS 10.2.1 )  but in
IPhone 5 (OS 9.3.5 )- doesnt work

Comment: How do you create the url, and what is the exact error message? Avoid messages like this without details.

Comment: I have given the error message in the question itself

Comment: Error message **CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme Failed to load: The file “Recording2017-03-06_11.08.53000.mp3” couldn’t be opened.**

Comment: And **How do you create the url**?

Comment: Thank was my problem fixed it